# wiring up laser pointer directly to usb power

Tags: batteries, laser-diode

I have a red cheap [laser pointer/lantern](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Laserpointer-3-in-1-Mini-Flashlight-Red-Laser-Pointer-Strong-Light-Pen-Money-Detector-Light-Funny/1753161758.html) which I'm using to do some experiments. But I find that the batteries have a very short lifetime for what I'm doing, It uses three LR44 button cell batteries,

from what I saw online, each battery is 1.5V so it needs around 4.5 volts, I'm not sure about the current though.

But I have a USB phone charger adapter that is rated at 5V and 1000mA

So my question is:
Can I wire the USB charger directly to the laser battery contacts without damaging it?

If not, what kind of circuit do I need to adapt the USB power for this?

Comment: My guess is that it's probably regulated and will work with a range of voltages, but without opening it up to see what the circuit is that is just speculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tear-down of a red laser (no LED) shows a very simple circuit (left):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKRFjt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the metal shell connects to laser *anode*, and is at the most positive voltage. The inner "springy" contact connects the battery negative terminal (through the series resistor and momentary switch) to laser cathode.

If you substitute 5V USB power source, an extra external series resistor to the "springy" contact is all that's required to keep laser current in the 20mA ballpark (right).
We often use USB DC connections with the assumption that the negative end is ground, and the positive end will be "hot". Not so with these cheap lasers - the shell connection should not be grounded.[image]

Answer (score 1):

A cheap laser point like this in the provided link doesn't have an internal regulator, it has only resistors, the laser LED, and the white LED for the lantern. I've already opened a bunch of them.

If powered directly with the USB charger, it would work, but probably this would reduce the lifespan of the LED.

An option would be replace the resistor inside, but probably is a SMD resistor and doesn't worth the work of find another one with the right value.

The easier way is adding just a diode in series with the lantern USB and lantern. Any diode, a 1N4148 if you have one, or even a 1N4001, 1N4004, 1N4007 (you can scavenge one of them from a burnt CFL lamp). The diode will reduce the 5V from USB to about 4.4V, that are safer for your LED diode.